# java generics incompatible types compilation error when types are the same

Tags: java

I cannot figure out why I receive the following compilation error `incompatible types: E cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends ...Event`

on

```
public <E extends Event> void publish(E event) {
    listeners.forEach(Listener<? extends Event> listener) -> {
            listener.handle(event); // <-----error occurs here
    })
}
```

```
public interface Listener<E extends Event> {
    void handle(E event);
}
```

To me things look fine, both are having the same parameter types.

Any ideas? I am using Java 19.

IntelliJ offers the following suggestion but I don't see how that would work.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To me things look fine, both are having the same parameter types.

You are incorrect.

I'm going to assume `listeners` is a `List<Listener<? extends Event>>`.  So, for example,

```
List<Listener<? extends Event>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
listeners.add(new Listener<FooEvent>() { ... });
```

Now, imagine I call

```
publish(new BarEvent());
```

This compiles, according to the definitions you have -- but the `Listener<FooEvent>` doesn't know what to do with a `BarEvent`.

You will have to redesign your event listeners -- perhaps to have one list of listeners for each different kind of event, or perhaps to have each listener know what kind of events it can and cannot handle.